# Good way to handle temporary file situation in PHP

Tags: php, image, upload, temporary-files

I have a PHP script where a user can upload an image.  This image is stored in the temporary directory and is returned to the user.  The user can then use a javascript interface to crop the image.  (x1,y2)(x2,y2) is sent to the script which is used to crop the image.  It is then returned to the user for another preview and\or crop.  Once the user is sufficiently satisfied he will click "save".  The temp file is copied over to the original and the temp deleted.  These are not per-user images, but rather images of equipment.  Any user in the organization can replace any image of equipment.  This approach is good but there are a few issues:

1) Let's say the user uploads an image for preview but then closes the browser window.  I will be left with a temporary file.  This can become an issue.  Sure I can have a CRON clean them up but in theory I can have a ton of temporary files (this is ugly).  The cron can also delete the user's temp file during an edit.

2) To deal with number 1 I can always have a temporary file per piece of equipment, such as equip1.temp and equip1.jpg.  All uploads are stored in equip1.temp, all commits are transfered to equip1.jpg.  If two users are trying to upload pictures of the same piece of equipment at the same time this could mess them up (highly unlikely + not an issue, but still ugly)

3) I can always pass the image back and forth (user "uploads" image and it get's echoed back as an `<img src="base64....." />`.  The resulting edits + original base64 string are sent back to PHP for processing).  This solution relieves the temp file issue but I noticed it takes several seconds to send high res images back and forth.

How would you deal with this situation?

Comment: use option#2, but also include the `user id` in the filename, like `equip1-user123.temp`.

Comment: What if user123 leaves the computer and never comes back?  The temp file will hang around forever.  With N many users there is N*#ofequip files

Comment: if the user is allowed to edit only one image at a time, you can save the filename in the user table. then run a cron regularly which deletes any file not present in the user table.

Comment: Good idea.  How would I deal with a user editing an image and just leaving?  The file will be in the user table indefinitely.  If all N users do this I still have the same issue.  Conversely i I had a cron just delete temp files every X seconds the user can be in the middle of an edit and have his edits wiped.

Comment: you would need a `last login` timestamp also in the table. After a month or two has passed without a login by the user, remove his temporary files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend #3 due to the reasons you mentioned.

I suggest you do this instead:

1. User uploads file to a random temporary name. `equip1.jpg` gets stored as `equip1_fc8293ae82f72cf7.jpg`. Be sure you script will juggle both file names around. It will allow two users to upload the same equipment, with the last one to upload being the winner, but no conflict along the way.
2. Everytime your cropper works with the temp image, you should "touch" it to update the modified time.
3. Let the user finish their edits, move the temp file in place of the final image name.
4. Have a cron, or a section of your uploader script, that deletes abandoned temp files that have a mtime older than an hour or so. You suggest this is messy, because of the potential of lots of temp files, but do you expect a lot of images to be abandoned? Garbage collection is a very standard method for this problem.

Comment: If the user uploads, crops, previews, and doesn't commit until > an hour (he had to go to a meeting) then his work will be lost.

Comment: I said an hour because I figured you were concerned about space more than anything. You could set it to 24+ hrs. At some point, you would have to handle that error, if a user came back after the weekend, but it would handle most situations very well.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue like this. If I recall correctly (its been a while), I ended up creating a table in a DB to store file names and session keys/time. Each time the script loaded, if there was a dead session in the database, the corresponding session and image/file was deleted.

I don't know if that's a good solution or not, but it solved the multiple user access problem for me.